# What would be an appropriate use of HTML or CSS tag

Tags: support

If code implementation is off topic in this community, then what would be suitable question regarding HTML or CSS? because the tags exist...

**What are HTML and CSS tags all about?**

Answer (score 7):

If you look at [the highest voted CSS questions](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/css?sort=votes), the top 6 have little or no code at all. The HTML tag is similar. So there is obviously scope for non-implementation questions. But that isn't to say implementation questions are off-topic per-se.

The [tag info](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/css/info) for CSS says (emphasis mine):

> Questions about cascading style sheets, commonly refered to as CSS. Ask anything related to implementing styles, effects or graphic-design-specific tasks. **For questions about implementing structural elements or anything completely unrelated to the aesthetic look, please go to Stack Overflow.**

Some questions will be clear-cut, some not so much. [Your question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/70049/how-to-prevent-objects-position-being-affected-by-other-elements), which I voted to close, was about using a `<div>` to create a background effect (which is about the aesthetics) and your problem was that `<div>` affecting the position and structure of the rest of your page (which certainly isn't). More importantly, your question was a very basic CSS question which should have been easily answerable with a Google search or basic CSS positioning tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

> What are HTML and CSS tags all about?

Questions around designing in the browser with HTML and CSS.

HTML and CSS isn't off topic but I believe the issue you're referring to with your question, "[How to prevent object's position being affected by other elements](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/70049/how-to-prevent-objects-position-being-affected-by-other-elements)" is you do not show what you've tried or include any code.